# NCover not picking up web application dlls

Tags: ncover

Im using NCover 1.5.8, and its doesn't seem to produce and metrics relating to my website applications. The ncover output indicates the tests relating to the website have been run.

Is there anything special I need to do for website dlls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NCover requires the PDB files to be present, else it just simply ignore it.